# What is the easiest way to add global keyboard shortcuts in Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like for my app to detect keyboard shortcuts when it isn't running, but as there doesn't appear facility to do this in Windows a reasonable fallback would be to have a background process without any UI that listens for keypresses. Is it possible to monitor keypresses when an app isn't in the foreground in .Net?

Looks like this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/mclhotkeynet.aspx) has what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx) is pretty good too

EDIT: I recently created this library, which uses a different approach: [NHotkey](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NHotkey)

Answer (score 7):

A Windows shortcut can have an associated hotkey - right-click on any program in your Start menu, go Properties, and you'll see a "Shortcut key" box.  Windows will then look for that hotkey on your behalf and launch your program when it sees it.  (I use it to make `Ctrl+Alt+C` launch Calculator.)

To set this up programmatically, use [IShellLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774950(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: How can I create a shell link programmatically?

Comment: Thank you for this. I had a web page opening every time I went to Save All (Ctrl+Shift+S) on any program and I couldn't figure out why. Turns out there was a Windows shortcut that had that that key combo set. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

By calling this API:

RegisterHotKey

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309.aspx

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html

Then override this method "WndProc" to monitor keypresses.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        // let the base class process the message
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        // if this is a WM_HOTKEY message, notify the parent object
        const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;
        if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY) ...............
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to make it non intrusive.

It is always intrusive to add global keyboard shortcut. If you have to do it anyways, make sure that it is an opt-in, not opt-out feature.